# JPA Attribute without indexing

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I am using JPA with EclipseLink 2.1 in a JSF application,

A JPA Entity has an attribute of a Long type that needs NO indexing. The default configuration creates an index in the table column.

How can I annotate NOT to create indexing for a particular attribute in a JPA Entity?

Comment: Show the entity.

Comment: JPA/EclipseLink doesn't automatically add indexing when using JPA schema generation. Show how you are creating the table and the annotations.